# How do I implement counting from a specific time using MomentJS

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I'm using [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) for real time (counting time) clock on my project. And is working perfectly. Here is my code:

```
interval = setInterval(function() {
    momentNow = moment();
    moment_time = momentNow.format('hh:mm:ss A');
    moment_date = momentNow.format('MMMM DD, YYYY') + ' ' 
        + momentNow.format('dddd')
        .substring(0,3).toUpperCase();
    // displays the time
    real_time.html(moment_time);
    real_date.html(moment_date);
}, 1000);
```

Like any human being, I wanted more from the plugin. I want to display a counting time from a specific time rendered from the interval say `momentNow = 02:22:30 PM`.

Basically, the logic is this,

Pseudo code:

```
interval = setInterval(function() {
    var started = "02:22:30 PM";
    rendered_time.html(started);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `moment.diff(timestamp)`

Example code

```
timestamp = moment().now()
setInterval(function() {
  rendered_time.html(moment(moment().diff(timestamp)).format("hh:mm:ss A"));
});
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: Note that this only works if the two points in time are less than 24 hours apart.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `from`([see the docs here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/)):

`moment([2007, 0, 28]).from([2007, 0, 27])`